# Creating a FileInputStream from a scanner/String

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, fileinputstream

Im trying to take a file name(location) from a command line input and then read the contents of that file.

```
public class Beekeeper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Garden garden = new Garden();
        System.out.println("Enter File Name Please");
        Scanner cmdReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String cmdInput = cmdReader.next();
        fileReader(cmdInput);
        //code removed
    }

    protected static void fileReader(FileInputStream fileName) {
        FileInputStream configFile = fileName;
        Scanner configScanner = new Scanner(configFile);
    //code removed
    }
}
```

Currently it isnt working as im trying to put a string as a parameter that is ment to be a FileInputStream but I'm trying to find a way to convert that string to a FileInputStream, or to get the FileInputStream strait from the cmd input.

Thanks for any help

Comment: `FileInputStream configFile = fileName;` should be `FileInputStream configFile = new FileInputStream (/* your file path*/);`

Comment: You are passing String, but your method signature is FileInputStream.

Comment: That simple sorry for stupid question think I've been doing this for too long with no sleep missing something so simple

Comment: @user1642671 This always happens with all of us, so don't feel bad. Now as you solved your problem then take some rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got your problem. You are passing `string` which is a file path.  You have to pass instace of `FileInputStream`

```
  fileReader(new FileInputStream (cmdReader));
```